# Problemas atualização de dados com entity Framework com dados relacionais

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho uma tabela Consulta que tem duas chaves estrangeiras (Cliente e Procedimento).

para adicionar uma nova consulta eu consigo normalmente, porem na hora de editar ele não muda meu Cliente ou Procedimento os outros campos modifica normalmente.

```
public static void EditarConsulta(Consulta entrada)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ConsultorioContext ctx = new ConsultorioContext())
            {
                ctx.Entry(entrada).State = EntityState.Modified;
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

outras formas que já tentei:

```
ctx.ChangeTracker.Entries<Consulta>().First(x => x.Entity == entrada).State = EntityState.Modified;

ctx.Entry<Consulta>(entrada).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucas, você está iniciando o context dentro do método, nesse caso o Entity não reconhece a entidade *original*.

Tente buscar a entidade original e setar o valores em cima dela usando o `SetValue`. Algo como:

```
var entidadeExistente = ctx.Consulta.Find(entidadeAlterada.Id);
ctb.Entry(entidadeExistente).CurrentValues.SetValues(entidadeAlterada);
```

Abraços